# Node.js Express - How do I dynamically serve model data?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Suppose I have an articleModel with a title and a body. I have a get route to render a list of all articles set up like this:

```
app.get("/articles", function(req, res) {
  articleMode.find()
    .then(function(articles) {
      res.render("articles.ejs", {articles: articles});
    });
});
```

The view contains embedded JS code that displays a list of the articles within anchor tags. There is a separate div tag for each article.

I wish to render an article title and body into that div, based on the article whose anchor tag is clicked. However, I do not want to redirect the user to another page (ie. route to "/articles/:id"); I want to serve this dynamically on the same page (ie. remain on "/articles").

I recall using jQuery and Ajax for this years ago but I haven't done it in a long time and my searches are not turning up what I need. I am looking for a general outline of how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require you to add an event handler on click that gets the `href` attribute from the clicked element. Then you can make an ajax request to that url and append it to the dom. Here is a basic outline:

```
// The click handler
$('a.article-link').click(function (e) {

  // Prevent navigation
  e.preventDefault();

  // Grab the href
  let $this = $(this);
  let href = $this.attr('href');

  // Make the request
  $.get(href)
  .done(function (response) {

    // Append the response to the parent of the a tag
    $this.closest('.article-content').append(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.